# Export map with legend using openlayers3

Tags: openlayers, export, legend

Is there any one who has an idea about how to export a thematic map that is accompanied with a legend (picture) using openlayers3? I searched in the openlayers documentation but I get a map without a legend.[image]

Comment: what about creating a canvas and export it? (so it gonna export everything on the screen)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but the problem is that: when I screen my map the tools also are creened (exemple:zoom)

Comment: check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41850514/7280641), it works to export map with legend by canvas